# Is there a way to replace the url with only the link that you click on?

Tags: reactjs

I have a footer with many links. Each link takes me to a new page that I have a template for each.

This works fine:
[image]

but when I click a link it stacks like this[image]

I need a way to reset the url so it only shows the last links url. This is what I have done so far without any luck

```
<Link to={`../${item.href}`}>{item.title}</Link>
```

Comment: remove the referrer ..  from `../${item.href}` and give actual url by variable or .env then it will solve the problem

Comment: Still no luck :/ @MdMahamudulHasan

Comment: could you please share more code then easy to help

Comment: It worked! I was coding in the wrong place xD. Thank you

Comment: nice !!   thank you :).